# How to refresh jQuery jTable on delete?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, jquery-jtable

I have used the jTable plugin of jQuery in my CRUD application. My problem is, when I click on the delete icon, a confirmation dialog appears in but after clicking the delete button the dialog doesn't disappear and I have to manually refresh the page to load the reflected table.

Here goes the screenshot of the problem:

[image]

Now the dialog doesn't disappear and when I manually click on the close button of the dialog, it shows:

[image]

I dont want this behaviour. I want on clicking the delete button the dialog will disappear as well as the table will be reloaded

**Here goes the script:**

```
 <div id="StudentTable" style="width: 580px; margin: auto;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        //Prepare jtable plugin
        $('#StudentTable').jtable({
            title: 'The Student List',
            actions: {
                listAction: '/jTableTest/StudentList',
                deleteAction: '/jTableTest/DeleteStudent',
                updateAction: '/jTableTest/UpdateStudent',
                createAction: '/jTableTest/CreateStudent'
            },
            fields: {
                id: {
                    key: true,
                    create: false,
                    edit: false,
                    list: false
                },
                name: {
                    title: 'Name',
                    width: '15%'
                },
                birthdate: {
                    title: 'Birth Date',
                    list: true,
                    width: '18%',
                    type: 'date',
                    displayFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
                }
            }
        });

        //Load person list from server
        $('#StudentTable').jtable('load');

    });

</script>
```

**Here goes the Delete action:**

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult DeleteStudent(int id)
        {
            try
            {
                //_personRepository.DeletePerson(personId);
                student student = db.students.Find(id);
                db.students.Remove(student);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return Json(new { Result = "OK" });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(new { Result = "ERROR", Message = ex.Message });
            }
        }
```

Comment: @Ravi I have added code, check it out please

Comment: if you are using firefox and firebug do you see any javascript error in the console?

Answer (score 2):

Ello, I was just having the same problem with add update and delete. What I ended up doing was tapping into the add, update and delete events and manually reloading the table.
See [Events](http://www.jtable.org/ApiReference#Events) in the documentation for more info.

```
<div id="StudentTable" style="width: 580px; margin: auto;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        //Prepare jtable plugin
        $('#StudentTable').jtable({
            title: 'The Student List',
            actions: {
                listAction: '/jTableTest/StudentList',
                deleteAction: '/jTableTest/DeleteStudent',
                updateAction: '/jTableTest/UpdateStudent',
                createAction: '/jTableTest/CreateStudent'
            },
            //What I added
            recordUpdated:function(event, data){
                $('#StudentTable').jtable('reload');
            },
            recordAdded: function (event, data) {
                $('#StudentTable').jtable('reload');
            },
            recordDeleted: function (event, data) {
                $('#StudentTable').jtable('reload');
            },

            fields: {
                id: {
                    key: true,
                    create: false,
                    edit: false,
                    list: false
                },
                name: {
                    title: 'Name',
                    width: '15%'
                },
                birthdate: {
                    title: 'Birth Date',
                    list: true,
                    width: '18%',
                    type: 'date',
                    displayFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
                }
            }
        });

        //Load person list from server
        $('#StudentTable').jtable('load');

    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

i don't see where is your delete code in javascript. but i do suggest this

```
$('#YourJqueryDialogbox').dialog('destroy');  // use this code in delete click event, once the delete action result returned.
```

Comment: look I have used jTable..it takes care of all those stuff. All I have to do is just to indicate the appropriate action method on  deleteAction: '/jTableTest/DeleteStudent' for example

Answer (score 1):

@Md. Arafat Al Mahmud

Try to change code like below:

```
 //ViewBag.ClientName is set to a random name in the Index action.
var myClientName = '@ViewBag.ClientName';

//Initialize jTable
$('#StudentTableContainer').jtable({
    title: 'Student List',
    actions: {
        listAction: '@Url.Action("StudentList")?clientName=' + myClientName,
        deleteAction: '@Url.Action("DeleteStudent")?clientName=' + myClientName,
        updateAction: '@Url.Action("UpdateStudent")?clientName=' + myClientName,
        createAction: '@Url.Action("CreateStudent")?clientName=' + myClientName
    },
   ......
   ......
```

Delete function:

```
//Define a function to get 'record deleted' events
    realTimeHub.RecordDeleted = function (clientName, recordId) {
        if (clientName != myClientName) {
            $('#StudentTable').jtable('deleteRecord', {
                key: recordId,
                clientOnly: true
            });
        }

        writeEvent(clientName + ' has <b>removed</b> 
        a record with id = ' + recordId, 'event-deleted');
    };
   -----
   -----
```

Delete function in controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult DeleteStudent(int studentId)
{
    try
    {
        //Delete from database
        _repository.StudentRepository.DeleteStudent(studentId);

        //Inform all connected clients
        var clientName = Request["clientName"];
        Task.Factory.StartNew(
            () =>
            {
                var clients = Hub.GetClients<RealTimeJTableDemoHub>();
                clients.RecordDeleted(clientName, studentId);
            });

        //Return result to current (caller) client
        return Json(new { Result = "OK" });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Json(new { Result = "ERROR", Message = ex.Message });
    }
}
------
------
```

code project example may help you [Real-time-Asynchronous-Web-Pages-using-jTable-Sign](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/315938/Real-time-Asynchronous-Web-Pages-using-jTable-Sign).

Comment: can u please provide me with an example ?

Comment: your problem is with processing delete operation, try to change code as described in the [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/315938/Real-time-Asynchronous-Web-Pages-using-jTable-Sign).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

the option animationsEnabled : false was the solution for me.

```
$('#...').jtable({
              title: 'Bestellingen',
              paging: true, //Enable paging
              sorting: true, //Enable sorting
              defaultSorting: 'date ASC',
              pageSize : 10,
              animationsEnabled : false,

              actions: {
                  listAction:  'content/.../data.php',
                  deleteAction: 'content/.../delete.php',
                  updateAction: 'content/.../save.php',
                  createAction: 'content/.../save.php'
              },...
```

Also your deleteSomething.php -file needs the reply with a json-array {"Result": "OK"}

```
echo json_encode(array("Result" => "OK" ));
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem while my Create Record message box was not disappearing at all. I solve the issue by adding "Record" attribute in the Json and set it's value to the record which is recently being created.

So I would suggest you to return your Json Object like return Json(new { Result = "OK", Record = deletedObject });

Hope it would work

Usman

Answer (score 0):

Well if you use MVC, try to return ActionResult instead of JsonResult in the delete function, everything else looks fine to me.

```
public ActionResult DeleteStudent(int studentId)
```